# C++ Efficient way to construct large vector of shared_ptr to class

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, shared-ptr, dynamic-allocation

I need to construct a large `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> many_ptr_to_A`.

Ideally, for `A` a non-default constructor with arguments is used.
Several variants are defined in the code sample below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <ctime>

class A
{
public:
    A(std::vector<double> data):
        data(data)
    {}
    A():
        data(std::vector<double>(3, 1.))
    {}

    std::vector<double> data;
};

int main()
{
    int n = 20000000;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> many_ptr_to_A;

    // option 1
    std::clock_t start = std::clock();
    std::vector<A> many_A(n, std::vector<double>(3, 1.));
    std::cout << double(std::clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    // end option 1

    many_ptr_to_A.clear();

    // option 2
    start = std::clock();
    many_ptr_to_A.reserve(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        many_ptr_to_A.push_back(std::shared_ptr<A>(new A(std::vector<double>(3, 1.))));
    }
    std::cout << double(std::clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    // end option 2

    many_ptr_to_A.clear();

    // option 3
    start = std::clock();
    A* raw_ptr_to_A = new A[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        many_ptr_to_A.push_back(std::shared_ptr<A>(&raw_ptr_to_A[i]));
    }
    std::cout << double(std::clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    // end option 3

    return 0;
}
```

### Option 1

Rather fast but unfortunately I need pointers instead of raw objects. A method to create pointers to the resulting allocated space and preventing the vector from deleting the objects would be great but I can't think of one.

### Option 2

This works and I can feed specific data in the constructor for every `A`. Unfortunately, this is rather slow. Using `std::make_shared` instead of `new` is not really improving the situation.

Even worse, this seems to be a big bottleneck when used in multiple threads. Assuming, that I run option 2 in 10 threads with `n_thread = n / 10`, instead of being around ten times faster the whole thing is around four times slower. Why does this happen? Is it a problem when multiple thread try to allocate many small pieces of memory?

The number of cores on the server I'm using is larger than the number of threads. The rest of my application scales nicely with the number of cores, thus this actually represents a bottleneck.

Unfortunately, I'm not really experienced when it comes to parallelization...

### Option 3

With this approach I tried to combine the fast allocation with a raw `new` at one go and the shared_ptrs. This compiles, but unfortunately yields a segmentation fault when the destructor of the vector is called. I don't fully understand why this happens. Is it because `A` is not POD?

In this approach I would manually fill the object-specific data into the objects after their creation.

### Question

How can I perform the allocation of a large number of `shared_ptr` to `A` in an efficient way which also scales nicely when used on many threads/cores?
Am I missing an obvious way to construct the `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> many_ptr_to_A` in one go?

My system is a Linux/Debian server. I compile with g++ and -O3, -std=c++11 options.

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Is the memory allocator your runtime is using protected by many locks? Making lots of small allocations can effectively serialize your code if this is the case.

Comment: I actually don't know, as already mentioned I'm rather new to parallelization...

I use normal std::threads. All threads work on their own set of variables. But of course they are accessing the same RAM (as far as I know?).

I'm on a Linux/Debian server and compile with g++ and -O3.

Comment: What compiler/runtime library are you using?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need shared pointers instead of object (or at worst raw pointers)?

Comment: Option 3 is undefined behaviour, you have `n` shared_ptrs which will all try to `delete` a single `A`, but there must be only one `delete[]` for the whole array, not `delete` used `n` times

Comment: I know with Visual Studio both `malloc` and `new` are serialized, which would be the cause, and the solution would be to be a smarter allocator.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Is there a way to point to already existing dynamically allocated memory with smart pointers without running into this problem?

Comment: @MooingDuck
Even if it is serialized, why is it so much slower then? Can you tell me more about smarter allocators?

Comment: @gondo, yes, the `shared_ptr` aliasing constructor. See my answer below.

Comment: @gondo: Why is option 2 slower than option 1?  Probably because it's doing twice as many allocations.  I'd expect it to be twice as slow.  If you guarantee that you're only going to allocate X at the start and never add more, you can use a _far_ faster allocator.

Comment: @MarkB I will have to move the objects between different vectors. Btw: using std::unique_ptr seems to actually slow it down. Some research showed that this might be related to g++...

Comment: Just curious, are you planning to move items between vectors in multithreaded code?

Comment: @MorphingDragon So far I'm strictly avoiding this and hopefully I'll also be able to avoid this in the future :)

Comment: So why do you even need `shared_ptr`, why can't you just keep have a `vector<A>` that you never modify and use `A*` instead of `shared_ptr<A>`? Managing ownership isn't an issue, because the vector owns the objects.

Comment: Some learning material on concurrent memory allocation if you're interested. https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/scalable-memory-allocation-using-jemalloc/480222803919

Comment: @JonathanWakely This might actually be an option even if I would have to change quite some things in the architecture...

Comment: I accepted the answer of @JonathanWakely.

Furthermore have I successfully applied his recommendation to use a std::vector<A> instead of shared_ptr... it has some drawbacks but works and is very fast. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 3 is undefined behaviour, you have `n` shared_ptrs which will all try to `delete` a single `A`, but there must be only one `delete[]` for the whole array, not `delete` used `n` times. You could do this though:

```
std::unique_ptr<A[]> array{ new A[n] };
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> v;
v.reserve(n);
v.emplace_back(std::move(array));
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
  v.push_back(std::shared_ptr<A>{v[0], v[0].get() + i});
```

This creates a single array, then creates `n` shared_ptr objects which *all share ownership of the array* and which each point to a different element of the array. This is done by creating one `shared_ptr` that owns the array (and a suitable deleter) and then creating `n-1` shared_ptrs that *alias* the first one, i.e. share the same reference count, even though their `get()` member will return a different pointer.

A `unique_ptr<A[]>` is initialized with the array first, so that `default_delete<A[]>` will be used as the deleter, and that deleter will be transferred into the first `shared_ptr`, so that when the last `shared_ptr` gives up ownership the right `delete[]` will be used to free the whole array. To get the same effect you could create the first shared_ptr like this  instead:

```
v.push_back(std::shared_ptr<A>{new A[n], std::default_delete<A[]>{}});
```

Or:

```
v.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<A[]>{new A[n]});
```

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation! A quick implementation seemed nearly as fast as option 2. I'll try this out on multiple cores tomorrow.

Hopefully this also scales nicely...

Comment: It only performs three allocations, one for the array of `A[n]`, one for the vector elements and one small allocation for the `shared_ptr` reference counting metadata. You could reduce that to just one allocation by using `vector<A>` and `A*` instead of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Is there a way to use a non-default constructor with arguments for A?

Comment: Only by providing arguments for every element: `new A[n]{ {..}, {..}, {..}, ... }` which doesn't work if you don't know `n` in advance. If you used `std::vector<A>` you can easily use different arguments for each element.